# Limit Command in R?

Tags: r, math

What is the take a limit command or function in R?

(I could not find it by searching using ? and ?? functions or in introductory manuals. lim() and limit() do not exist.)

This is in the sense of limit X->Y+ of F(X). I don't mean anyone writing code; I mean, included in R as installed standard, what the supplied function is called.

(Note: my previous question on this topic has been edited to be fully clear ... but it is still on hold... I suppose that moderators forgot about it ... hence this question.)

Comment: That question is still on hold for some reason even though it was edited a while ago. I edited it again but I guess mods won' reopen it because it was forgotten. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Or won't re-open it because it was off-topic, for reasons given in the comments to that question.

Comment: It seems to be on topic, easy to answer, and there is nowhere else to ask it. I suggest this is the best place to find somebody who knows the answer and that it is a useful question to know the answer to. There is not much mathematics that can be done if limits cannot be taken.

Comment: Even if that was true (lots of math can be done without the need to take any general form of a limit) why would you require the function to be a part of base R? Honestly in the future don't be that presumptuous - if it's in a package instead why should that matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ryacas package can do limits:

```
library(Ryacas)     # version 1.1.1
x <- ysym("x")      # define x as a symbolic variable
lim(sin(x)/x, x, 0) # limit of sin(x)/x as x approaches 0
## 1
```

or in Ryacas0

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x") # define x as a symbolic variable
Limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0) # limit of sin(x)/x as x approaches 0
## expression(1)
```

Also the rSymPy package:

```
library(rSymPy)    # version 0.2-1.2
sympy("var('x')")  # define x as a symbolic variable
## [1] "x"
sympy("limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0)")
## [1] "1"
```