# How to do basic limits?

Tags: r

I have been researching how to do basic limits in R for quite some time and can't seem to find a working answer. I have seen [Limit Command in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584501/limit-command-in-r) however even after I downloaded Ryacas and use the limit function, Ryacas tells me that they no longer use the Limit function. They offer downloading their old version, but I have not been able to get that to work either. The other package (rSymPy) is not working for me either.

The equation I am trying to solve is:

limx→0 (sin(x)/x)

Please let me know if there is any way to solve this issue! Thank you!

Edit: here is the error message I am getting:

```
>Limit(x,0)
Error in Limit(x, 0) : 
This function is defunct in this version of Ryacas, but still exists in 
the legacy package Ryacas0 (https://github.com/mikldk/ryacas0) if you need it.

Please refer to the vignette 'Getting started' 
(http://mikldk.github.io/ryacas/articles/getting-started.html) for 
information on how this new, improved version of Ryacas works.

This function will be removed entirely in next version of Ryacas.
```

Also, I am doing such a basic limit in R for a school project. As I'm sure you can tell I'm very new to this, so thanks for all your help!

Comment: Show the code you tried, or the exact error messages you are getting. That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Why are you trying to use R for such a basic limit? It can be done by hand in numerous ways (e.g. by L'Hospital's Rule).